# ContentFlow reflection issue with Chrome on Mac

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

It appears that the excellent carousel library ContentFlow has reflection issues with Chrome on Mac (I am using Lion).  Seems to be fine on PC. Visit http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/ in Chrome and you'll see in the example the images are incorrectly mirrored with a shady part at the top as per the below screenshots.  Is there a fix / workaround?  It doesn't seem that there is active development on ContentFlow anymore, which is a shame.

I'm using Chrome 16.0.912.75, on Mac (Lion)

****EDIT**** Screenshots

Proper (from Safari)
[image]

Broken (from Chrome)
[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing it any different in Firefox, same exact version of Chrome as you. Maybe a screenshot would be in order? And yeah it looks like 2 years since an update, so I doubt you'll be hearing from the developer.

Comment: Added screenshots.  Also mentioned I am on mac.

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue open here: http://code.google.com/p/contentflow/issues/detail?id=34

People tried different things, but it breaks on Windows' Chrome :(